# Unable to connect password protected MySQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have a website hosted at godaddy (say "**abc.co.in**"). After having logged into cpanel through my cpanel id and password (say "**siteid**" and "**sitepw**" respectively), i went ahead and created a MySQL Database named "**myDb**". Now i assigned a user to that database and granted all privileges. Say my database user id and password are "**dbUser**" and "**dbPw**" respectively.
Now i want to Add a table to this database using php.. However, upon connecting, using the following code:

> $con=mysqli_connect("abc.co.in","dbUser","dbPw","myDb");

i get an error :

> Warning:mysqli_connect():(HY000/1045) - Access denied for user 'dbUser'@'xxx.xxx.x.xxx' (using password: YES)"

Now i read somewhere that my user name needs to be of the format **"cpanel-username_mysql-username"**, i.e., in this case: **"siteid_dbUser"**, whilst password still sticking to the database password. However, It still returns me the same error message.
Am i typing the first parameter, 'hostname' incorrect? It doesn't need to be "**localhost**", does it? 
Kindly help for i am gravely confused. I know it might seem like a repetitive question but i checked a lot of posts here but couldn't find a solution..

Thanks in advance!

--EDIT--
Just for the record, the php file in which i'm trying to establish the connection and trying to add a table to my database is a local php file running on localhost. Just thought i'd mention it, incase it makes a difference.
--EDIT 2--
Okay so according to [THIS](http://forums.cpanel.net/f354/connecting-php-page-mysql-database-56011.html) link, even my database name needs to change.. hence modifying my code to

> $con=mysqli_connect("abc.co.in","siteid_dbUser","dbPw","siteid_myDb");

I tried it out but all in vain..  Still the same error message. I even changed the host to "localhost" and tried the same but it just doesn't connect.

Comment: The password is probably wrong.

Comment: nah, I double checked it.. The password is same as the User's password assigned to the database.. What i don't get is do i not need to somewhere provide my cpanel password too? if so, where??

Comment: make sure that the user you created for mysql has the correct IP associated with it.  If, for example, you created the user connecting as `localhost`, it will not work if you are trying to connect via `192.168.1.X`.  It might not even work with `127.0.0.1`